# How can I decide which Hypothesis Function and Decision Boundary to use in a 14-feature Logistic Regression model?

Tags: logistic-regression

I am trying to implement a Multivariate Logistic Regression model with 14 features. For 2 features, we can visualize the data using a scatter plot and manually decide on the hypothesis function and decision boundary. How can I do the same for 14 features? Is there a way to visualize such data? If not, how can I achieve a good fit?

Comment: Do you want to get the optimum value for a multiparametric regression or you just want to represent such data for user?

Comment: I want to visualize the data so that I can come up with a hypothesis that would be a good fit for the training set

Answer (score 0):

Here the way i do this. I have a multiparametric dataset and i need to represent the map of values. Every dataset have the independed values (parametres) and the depended values (functions). And i just give the user choise what the function should be represented on map and what parametres are plotted on axises. Others parametres (not axises) user can change homself by choosing the values from lists.
[image]

and the same map after user change some parametres:
[image]